# How to write code for a sort that will work in any workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("timesheet_report_2019-12-08_thr").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("timesheet_report_2019-12-08_thr").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("E2:E62"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("timesheet_report_2019-12-08_thr").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("B2:B62"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("timesheet_report_2019-12-08_thr").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A62"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("timesheet_report_2019-12-08_thr").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:I62")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

This is a macro I recorded to sort data for me. Each week to active worksheet changes names. How do I get it to where it will work on any sheet?

Comment: Use `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: I am pretty sure you could just use: `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet ...`

Answer (score 0):

Sort is a method that is accessible through worksheet objects.  However you choose to reference a worksheet object is up to you.

The method that excel has transcribed for you in the macro recorder uses the worksheet's name as an index.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("timesheet_report_2019-12-08_thr").Sort...
```

Notice that the name is in quotes and is therefore a string.  You could create a string variable.  The following code does the same work as above.

```
Dim worksheetName as String
worksheetName = "timesheet_report_2019-12-08_thr"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetName).Sort...
```

But you can also use numeric indexes.  This would sort whatever sheet the workbook thinks is first in the collection.  (this can be a bit misleading so be careful doing it this way.  The first sheet in the collection isn't always the leftmost tab, or even the sheet named "Sheet1").

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort...
```

You can also use certain keywords to reference a worksheet.  Some commenters have suggested ActiveSheet.  That works, because it references a worksheet object.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort...
```

And, you can get references out of an iterator, like in a "for each" loop.  The following code (complete with sort) will run the sort you've designed on every sheet in the workbook.

```
Sub SortAllSheets()

    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        With s.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=s.Range("E2:E62"), Order:=xlAscending
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=s.Range("B2:B62"), Order:=xlAscending
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=s.Range("A2:A62"), Order:=xlAscending
            .SetRange s.Range("A1:I62")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

    Next s

End Sub
```

So, there are lots of ways to run your sort "in any workbook".  Hope it helps.